# Problem with understanding the cdf solution from the Finan Course

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, self-learning

I am reading the [course by Finan](https://people.cas.uab.edu/%7Epjung/teaching_files/ProbabilityForActuaries.pdf), in **Example 22.5**, on p.213 one can see the Solution:

Determine the constant $c$ so that the following function is a pdf.
$$f(t) = 
\begin{cases} 
\frac{15}{64} + \frac{x}{64}, & -2 \leq x \leq 0,  \\ 
\frac{3}{8} + cx, &  0 < x \leq 3, \\ 
0, \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
Calculate $P(-1 \leq X \leq 1)$ and find $F(x)$.

Solution

Observe that $f$ is discontinuous at the points $-2$ and $0$, and is potentially
also discontinuous at the point 3. We first find the value of $c$ that makes $f$ a pdf.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
1 &= \int_{-2}^0 \left( \frac{15}{64} + \frac{x}{64} \right) dx +
\int_{0}^3 \left( \frac{3}{8} + cx \right) dx = \\
&=
\left( \frac{15}{64}x + \frac{x^2}{128}  \right) \bigg\rvert^0_{-2} +
\left( \frac{3}{8}x + \frac{cx^2}{8}  \right) \bigg\rvert^3_{0} = \\ \newline
&= \frac{30}{64} - \frac{2}{64} + \frac{9}{8} + \frac{9c}{2} = \frac{100}{64} + \frac{9c}{2}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Solving for $c$ we find $c = -\frac{1}{8}.$

The probability $P(-1 \leq X \leq 1)$ is calculated as follows.
$$P(-1 \leq X \leq 1) = \int_{-1}^0 \left( \frac{15}{64} + \frac{x}{64} \right) dx +
\int_{0}^1 \left( \frac{3}{8} + \frac{x}{8} \right) dx = \frac{69}{128}.$$

For $-2 \leq x \leq 0$ we have
$$
F(x) = \int_{-2}^x \left( \frac{15}{64} + \frac{t}{64} \right) dt = 
\frac{x^2}{128} + \frac{15}{64}x + \frac{7}{16}
$$
and for $0 < x \leq 3$
$$
F(x) = \int_{-2}^0 \left( \frac{15}{64} + \frac{x}{64}\right)dx + \int_0^x \left(\frac{3}{8} - \frac{t}{8}\right) dt = 
\frac{7}{16} + \frac{3}{8}x - \frac{1}{16}x^2.
$$

**Question**. Why in the last equation for the $0 < x \leq 3$ were used two integrals? And why is the first integral definite?

Comment: The last equation is still evaluating $\int_{-2}^xf(t)\text{ d}t$, but in calculating this integral it is more convenient to break it up as the sum of integrals over $[-2,0]$ and $[0,x]$ since the function is defined by different expressions over these two intervals.